# Communicate between two docker containers running on different machine with docker network (ssh)

Tags: docker

I  want to connect two docker containers running on different machine wihout docker swarm . Is it possible to achieve that with port 22 and docker networking?

In same node i am able to communicate  using local ip and bridge/MacVlan network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use docker swarm if you are trying to access different docker machine as it will create overlay networks over all connected docker daemon. If you don't want to use docker swarm you can use host network for both docker daemon. It will remove network isolation between host and containers so that you can access containers using host IP itself.

Comment: suppose I have 3 containers running in one machine and 3 containers running in another machine. i want to  do ssh(port 22) from one container to another conntainer. Is it  possible without private ip. If i am using hot network it wont have a private ip right?

Answer (score 2):

This works fine, if you make sure to use `docker run -p` to publish each container's network ports via the host, and connect between services using the *hosts'* DNS names or IP addresses.

```
server1$ docker run -p 12345:22 -e CONTAINER2_HOST=server2 -e CONTAINER2_PORT=24680 imagename
server2$ docker run -p 24680:22 -e CONTAINER1_HOST=server1 -e CONTAINER1_PORT=12345 imagename
```

Once you leave the current system (assuming you're not using a dedicated container orchestrator) you can't see "how" things work from a different system.  From the point of view of server2, `http://server1:12345` reaches the service in container1; but it doesn't know or care if that service is running in Docker or a VM or directly on the host.